# Why didn't the particle-antiparticle pairs collided at the LEP and Tevatron just instantly annihilate into pure energy? (presumably gamma rays?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, antimatter, virtual-particles, large-hadron-collider

I wonder if the fact that protons and antiprotons are roiling seas of non-valence quarks and such with very brief lifetimes means that when they collided at Fermilab they were not perfectly identical (but antisymmetric), therefore producing many different exotic things... But...

What about the pre-LHC, LEP collider?  Granted, it produced far fewer interesting and exotic things, but why any at all?  Who not just two gamma rays going in opposing directions?

Answer (score 3):

When particles collide and annihilate, the available energy can be used in any way that is compatible with various conservation laws (energy, leptonic number…)

Physicists can compute *branching ratios*, which are the probabilities for all those possibles outcomes.

Two resulting photons is only one possibility among many, there's no reason to assume that it'd be the only one.

Comment: To add more: the reason there is so many possibilities is that the electrons are positrons are accelerated to huge energies, so the center-of-mass energy of the system is huge. If the electrons would meet positrons at speeds close to zero, production of the two photons is essentially the only nontrivial process allowed by energy conservation.